# Scrapy post request form data

Tags: python-2.7, post, scrapy

I want to get the search result using scrapy post request after giving the input to CP Number as 16308 https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?TabID=100 .

Here is my scrapy spider code :--

```
def parse(self, response):
    head=response.xpath('//span[@id="dnn_ctlHeader_dnnBreadcrumb_lblBreadCrumb"]/span[@class="SkinObject"]/text()').extract_first()
    view_gen = response.xpath('//input[@id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]/@value').extract_first()
    dnn= response.xpath('//input[@id="__dnnVariable"]/@value').extract_first()
    view_state = response.xpath('//input[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]/@value').extract_first()
    view_val = response.xpath('//input[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]/@value').extract_first()

    data={
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':view_gen,
            '__dnnVariable':dnn,
            '__VIEWSTATE':view_state,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION':view_val,
            'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber':'16803',
            'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$ddlMemberType':'0'

    }
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(response.url,formdata=data,callback=self.fun)
```

**Response** 
 DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?tabid=100&error=An%20unexpected%20error%20has%20occurred&content=0> (referer: https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?TabID=100)
[]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes , I have posted my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Response DEBUG: Crawled (200)
>   https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?tabid=100&error=An%20unexpected%20error%20has%20occurred&content=0>
>   (referer: https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?TabID=100) []

Your question is how to avoid getting this error right? Try to be more specific in the future.

When you want to scrape a webpage you have to inspect it all on your browser, see all parameters that are being sent with the request and make sure you are doing the same on your spider. You got lots of parameters on your code, but not all.

See my code bellow which actually solves your problem:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'icsi'

    start_urls = ['https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?TabID=100']

    search_action_url = 'https://www.icsi.in/Student/Default.aspx?TabID=100'

    def parse(self, response):
        formdata = dict()
        for input in response.css('form#Form input'):
            name = input.xpath('./@name').get()
            value = input.xpath('./@value').get()
            formdata[name] = str(value) if value else ''
        formdata['dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber'] = '16308'
        formdata['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch'

        return scrapy.FormRequest(self.search_action_url, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse_search)

    def parse_search(self, response):
        scrapy.shell.inspect_response(response, self)
        return
```

You were missing the parameter `__EVENTTARGET`, which informs the site you hit the button "Search".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and the code provided by you is working fine for me.

Comment: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_YzE2OWNmYTYtOTdjNi00MjFiLTkyMDYtNjBkMzIzZTgzNWM3%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%228a5faebf-6078-418c-b7a8-7e077e8dd23b%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%226b60dad4-9375-4e5f-bf08-ae4e82a7c5eb%22%7d